# increase rank based on particular value in column

Tags: sql

I would appreciate some help for below issue. I have below table

| id | items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product |
| 2 | Tea |
| 3 | Coffee |
| 4 | Sugar |
| 5 | Product |
| 6 | Rice |
| 7 | Wheat |
| 8 | Product |
| 9 | Beans |
| 10 | Oil |

I want output like below. Basically I want to increase the rank when item is 'Product'. May I know how can I do that? For data privacy and compliance purposes I have modified the data and column names

| id | items | ranks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product | 1 |
| 2 | Tea | 1 |
| 3 | Coffee | 1 |
| 4 | Sugar | 1 |
| 5 | Product | 2 |
| 6 | Rice | 2 |
| 7 | Wheat | 2 |
| 8 | Product | 3 |
| 9 | Beans | 3 |
| 10 | Oil | 3 |

I have tried Lag and lead functions but unable to get expected output

Comment: Don't tag conflicting products; just tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. *"I have tried Lag and lead functions but unable to get expected output"* you forgot to include said attempt in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution using a derived value of 1 or 0 to denote data boundaries SUM'ed up with the ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING option, which is key here.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    items,
    SUM(CASE WHEN items='Product' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as ranks
FROM
```

Comment: That's indeed what I want.